# Android singleTask on Titanium 5.x--can it be made to work?

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-mobile

Running into a problem with Titanium 5.5.1 while trying to implement Android URL intent-filters. When using android:launchMode="singleTask" we are hitting the problem of the window hanging on launch as described in https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-15253. We've tried all the workarounds listed there but none works acceptably.

Suggestions? Other workarounds we can try, without having to upgrade to 6.x? Is upgrading to 6.0 or 6.1 the only way to fix this problem?

Comment: only way to do it is indeed upgrade. 6.0 is already out